# Hard Identifying function problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there any distinct functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$ and $g(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$? I honestly don't know where to begin with this one, although I do know that if $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, then $f$ is a line going through the origin.

Comment: I would experiment with different functions to get a feel for it. Try $f(x)=2x$. Then $f(a+b)=2(a+b)$, $f(a)=2a$, and $f(b)=2b$. Then try $f(x)=x^2$ and some function that you know does not pass through the origin (many won't). I'm not sure what you're looking for but on the surface it looks like $f(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Specialize to $b=0$ and notice that for all $a$ \begin{cases}f(a)-g(a)=g(0)\\ g(a)-f(a)=f(0)\end{cases}

So $g(x)=f(x)+f(0)$ for all $x$ and, moreover, $g(0)=-f(0)$. Therefore $-f(0)=g(0)=2f(0)$. So $f(0)=0$ and actually $g=f$.

Your assertion after "although I do know" is famously incorrect, though arguing about that is out of the scope of this post.

Comment: Could you add a link to the famously incorrect part?

Comment: It's been asked dozens of times on this site alone, not to mention elsewhere.